# Mysql - How to compare two Json objects?

Tags: mysql, json

What is the syntax to compare an entire MySql json column with a json object?

The following doesn't work:

```
select count(criteria) from my_alerts where criteria = '{"industries": ["1"], "locations": ["1", "2"]}'
```

I get a count of 0 even when the criteria column has value `{"industries": ["1"], "locations": ["1", "2"]}`

correct me if I'm wrong  but two JSON objects are equal if they have the same set of keys, and each key has the same value in both objects. The order of the keys and values is ignored. So the following should be the same?

```
 {"industries": ["1"], "locations": ["1", "2"]} = {"locations": ["2", "1"], "industries": ["1"]}
```

*** Update ***

I've managed to get it working by casting to json as follows:

```
select count(criteria) from my_alerts where criteria = CAST('{"industries": ["1"], "locations": ["1", "2"]}' AS JSON)
```

However whilst the order of the keys is ignored during the comparison the order of the values is still compared. So the following is falsy:

```
{"locations": ["1", "2"]} = {"locations": ["2", "1"]}
```

Is there any way to force the comparison to ignore order of the values aswell?

Comment: Pls provide some sample data for us to test.

Comment: @Shadow sample data in `criteria` column which is of data type json is `{"industries": ["1"], "locations": ["1", "2"]}`

Comment: It seems like yes, you should be able to compare the objects and they should evaluate to true based on the docs: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html#json-comparison

Comment: In JSON, contents of an array `[]` are equal IFF the values are the same and are in the same order. `[1,2,3] != [3,1,2]`

Comment: `Two JSON arrays are equal if they have the same length and values in corresponding positions in the arrays are equal.`, see [11.6 The JSON Data Type::Comparison and Ordering of JSON Values::Array](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html#json-comparison).

Answer (score 12):

You can do this using `JSON_CONTAINS`:

```
SELECT COUNT(criteria) 
FROM my_alerts 
WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(criteria,'{"industries": ["1"], "locations": ["1", "2"]}')
```

This perform a comparison that ignores the order of the values, which is critical because MySQL will re-order JSON properties for efficiency on INSERT.

Comment: May be use JSON_LENGTH beside to make sure that json perfectly equal

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`CAST()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast) function:

```
SELECT count(criteria)
FROM my_alerts 
WHERE criteria = CAST('{"industries": ["1"], "locations": ["1", "2"]}' AS JSON)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using MySQL 5.7.8 or higher you should be able compare a json column to a json object with the following syntax. The order of inserted keys value pairs doesn't matter.

```
SELECT json_col = JSON_OBJECT('foo', 'bar', 'color', 'red') FROM table1;
```

Test this by creating the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`table1` (
  `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `json_col` JSON NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;
```

Insert data into the table. Note the reversed order in the last inserted row. The fifth row has an additional key value pair.

```
INSERT INTO `mydb`.`table1` (`json_col`) VALUES ('{\"foo\": \"bar\", \"color\": \"red\"}');
INSERT INTO `mydb`.`table1` (`json_col`) VALUES ('{\"color\": \"blue\"}');
INSERT INTO `mydb`.`table1` (`json_col`) VALUES ('{\"color\": \"green\"}');
INSERT INTO `mydb`.`table1` (`json_col`) VALUES ('{\"foo\": \"bar\", \"color\": \"red\"}');
INSERT INTO `mydb`.`table1` (`json_col`) VALUES ('{\"foo\": \"bar\", \"color\": \"red\", \"baz\": 2}');
INSERT INTO `mydb`.`table1` (`json_col`) VALUES ('{\"color\": \"red\"}');
INSERT INTO `mydb`.`table1` (`json_col`) VALUES ('{\"color\": \"red\"}');
INSERT INTO `mydb`.`table1` (`json_col`) VALUES ('{\"color\": \"red\", \"foo\": \"bar\"}');
```

Now by using the following query:

```
SELECT 
json_col, 
json_col = JSON_OBJECT('foo', 'bar', 'color', 'red'), 
json_col = JSON_OBJECT('color', 'red', 'foo', 'bar') 
FROM table1;
```

We get:

```
{"foo": "bar", "color": "red"}  1   1
{"color": "blue"}   0   0
{"color": "green"}  0   0
{"foo": "bar", "color": "red"}  1   1
{"baz": 2, "foo": "bar", "color": "red"}    0   0
{"color": "red"}    0   0
{"color": "red"}    0   0
{"foo": "bar", "color": "red"}  1   1
```

Note that the order in the json object doesn't matter either. Additional keys matter however.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(criteria) 
FROM my_alerts 
WHERE criteria = JSON_EXTRACT('{"industries": ["1"], "locations": ["1", "2"]}', '$')
```

And I don't think you can compare objects ignoring the order of array items since its conflicts with the JSON array definition:

> A JSON array contains zero, one, or more ordered elements, separated
> by a comma.