# How to check for ANY like elements in JSON array in MySQL

Tags: mysql, json

I have a row in table A of JSON array of integers.

I have a table B whose rows have a field of a (possibly empty) JSON array of objects, and each object has a 'parent' field.

```
  table A
+-----------+
| foo       |
+-----------+
| [1, 2]    |
+-----------+

  table B
+--------------------------------+
| bar                            |
+--------------------------------+
| [{"parent": 1}]                |
| [{"parent": 2}, {"parent": 3}] |
| [{"parent": 4}]                |
| []                             |
+--------------------------------+
```

How do I get the rows from table B whose objects in bar don't have any parent matching any element in foo? i.e. the last 2 rows here should be returned.

I tried doing something with `SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(bar, '$[*].parent') FROM B`, but the result is a JSON array

```
+-----------------------------------------+
| SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(bar, '$[*].parent') |
+-----------------------------------------+
| [1]                                     |
| [2, 3]                                  |
| [4]                                     |
| NULL                                    |
+-----------------------------------------+
```

and the function `JSON_CONTAINS()` doesn't return partial matches:

"A candidate array is contained in a target array if and only if every element in the candidate is contained in some element of the target." [MySQL docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-contains)

Any help is greatly appreciated. MySQL version 5.7.22

Comment: Can you not do this comparison in your application's programming language? It honestly seems to me that you are going to have trouble doing it in mysql. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44767211/mysql-how-to-compare-two-json-objects

Comment: I'd prefer to have it done in pure mysql because I need to join the returned data to more stuff so I want to avoid having to loop and do another database fetch. Just wanted to see if anybody had a creative mysql-only solution

Comment: Have you considered denormalizing this instead of using JSON fields? You might get it to work, but it's not going to be fast.

Comment: @Evert wouldn't that be 'normalising'?

Comment: @Strawberry oops yes!

Comment: In case you can create a stored procedure, here are some ideas that may be useful, see [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=fa66263d36d4d1bf999f4ab413397d17). Be careful with performance problems.

Answer (score 0):

A little late to the game on this, but you may be able to leverage mysql's native json parsing:

`SELECT * FROM B WHERE B.json_field_name->'$.parent'  NOT IN (CAST(SELECT A.field_name_containing_ints WHERE` ...something that selects your integers... `AS ARRAY))`

Performance can be slow with large data sets, but I believe this is inline with what you're looking for. Sorry not to have any citations or docs on this - just coming out of my brain, but hopefully this is inline with what was needed, or can help someone else.